# Get Audio Files From Dropbox iOS Core API

Tags: ios, audio, dropbox-api

I need to list all the audio files from the user's Dropbox. I already configured my app on the Developer Console to have the corresponding permissions. Now that I already authenticated the user, I can retrieve all the directories but I want a method that goes into every folder and list the AudioFiles it can find. Currently my method does that but I have three concerns.

1. The method is kind of slow (Recursive)
2. I am getting this two random errors (probably due to multiple request per second)

   Listing a random folder.

   ```
   2015-06-02 12:44:52.634 Podbox[9038:2918749] Error loading metadata: Error      
   Domain=dropbox.com Code=503 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
   (dropbox.com error 503.)" UserInfo=0x170270780 {path=/ios 
   dev/passbook/signpass/signpass.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/gsteele.xcuserdatad, 
   error=Rate limiting oauth_accesses_per_access_token}
   ```

   Accessing Music

   ```
   2015-06-02 12:44:32.665 Podbox[9038:2918749] Error loading metadata: Error 
   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
   (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" 
   UserInfo=0x17047cf00 {path=/music/Blink 182/Unknown Album}
   ```
3. I know im just getting MP3 files. Is there a way to get all the Media Files without checking all their PathExtensions?

Currently I am trying something like this:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

  if (metadata.isDirectory) {

    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {

            if (file.isDirectory) {

                [self.restClient loadMetadata:file.path];

            } else if ([file.path.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"mp3"]){

                NSLog(@"    %@", file.filename);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata method will certainly be inefficient when used recursively like this, so instead, you'll want to use the `loadDelta` method:

```
/* Loads a list of files (represented as DBDeltaEntry objects) that have changed since the cursor was generated */
- (void)loadDelta:(NSString *)cursor;

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedDeltaEntries:(NSArray *)entries reset:(BOOL)shouldReset cursor:(NSString *)cursor hasMore:(BOOL)hasMore;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadDeltaFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

There's a blog post here (albeit for Python) that covers the basic idea of how to use this:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/12/efficiently-enumerating-dropbox-with-delta/

This should be a more efficient method in your case, resolving your first two issues.

It doesn't offer a way to filter to specific file types on the server though, so you'll need to do that client-side.